# android memory trouble when start a activity?

Tags: android, memory

I've got a problem with my app when I try to open a new activity but this occurs just sometimes. The error I can see on tablet is:

**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class**

On DDMS LogCat messages I can see whe fail occur:

**11-21 13:15:46.709: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(3379): Out of memory on a 4070416-byte allocation.**

Im a bit losed, could anyone guide me to solve the problem please??¿?,

thanks a lot.

Comment: can you post some code that you are using?

Comment: List of the contents in the resources directory and the code for more info.

Answer (score 1):

seems that xml which you want to inflate is doing something with large image, so you are running out of heap memory. Android provides each Application some VMBudget size, If your application needs more heap memory that it causes error like `ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(3379): Out of memory on a 4070416-byte allocation`. Well its just a guess. If this is not your case then plz paste your code/xml content where you are getting this error.

Comment: try {
               
             pictureWine = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.butPictureDesc); 
          try{
           if(vinico.getPicture().contains("file"))
            {
                Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(vinico.getPicture());
                pictureWine.setImageURI(imgUri);
            }                                                                                                                                         That's the code I use to load some images (sometimes 50) on my activity, maybe should I use garbage collector or load the images in other way?,.

Comment: yes that is the problem, if they are little more in size, then 50 images are enough for out of memory error.